# Slick: filter with Rep[Seq[T]]

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm working on a Play! project (in Scala) for which I am using slick.

I'm having an issue when trying to filter a query on a jsonb column which contains several arrays.

For example my config column contains the following json:

```
{
 test1: {
   ...
 },
 test2: [
   {
    id: ...,
    bool: false
   },
   {
    id: ...,
    bool: true
   }
 ]
}
```

I want to query this table and select each row for which at least 1 of test2 elements has bool: true. (we may have approx 10 elements in test2).

I can try each element of test2 1 by 1:

```
    baseQuery.filter(a => a.config+>'test2'~>0+>>'bool' === "true" ||
                          a.config+>'test2'~>1+>>'bool' === "true" ||
                          ...
                    )
```

But this is obviously not a good solution.

I tried going with:

```
baseQuery.filter(a => (a.config+>'test2').arrayElements[JsArray].value...
                    )
```

But the Rep[JsArray] has no value method.
I also tried using

```
arrayElements[Seq[JsValue]]
```

But I end up with a Rep[Seq[JsValue]] on which i cannot map/flatMap/exists/...

It has to stay a Query and not a DBIOAction so I don't have to reformat a lot of code...

Thanks everyone for your solutions/ideas !

Comment: You can't do more in slick query than you can in SQL. You could first write it in sql and then translate it to slick dsl. I am not sure if it is possible in SQL though.

Comment: Thank you for you answer Łukasz !
I think there should be a way in SQL using json_each,  however this method isn't implemented in slick... I found a "hack" for my issue that I will post as answer if someone ends up with the same problem.
Thanks again for you help.

Comment: Sure. I had smilar types of struggles before. I am not sure if this helps as I am not familiar with json in postgres, but you maybe can add an operator/function to slick yourself e.g. by analyzing the source code of plugin you are using. You can also take a look at this blog post https://virtuslab.com/blog/smooth-operator-with-slick-3/ for adding operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some "hackish" solution to solve my issue.
I'm not entirely happy with it as I would have prefer to properly iterate over a Seq[JsValue] but here it is if someone has the same problem.

This is pretty straightforward, I'm using the `+>>` operator to get my JsValue as a string and then use the `like` to see if it contains the boolean I need set to true.

With the same (stupid) example as before, the solution would be:

```
baseQuery.filter(_.config+>>'test2' like "%\"bool\": true%")
```

This is probably not the best solution but it works for what I needed.